# Select next subsequent change of certain column in a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with a unique index on Contracts of Customers that live in Houses. I want to know the days per house how long it takes when someone moves out (Contract end date) and a new contracts starts. For that I want to know what the first next contract will be in that house, but on the same row as the old contract for a (potentially different) customer.

This how the table currently looks like, I select the top 10 here:

```
SELECT TOP 10
PMCCONTRACT.ACCOUNTNUM  --Customer
,PMCCONTRACT.RENTALOBJECTID --House
,PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTID --Contract & Unique index of the table
,PMCCONTRACT.VALIDFROM  --Contract Start Date
,PMCCONTRACT.VALIDTO    --Contract End Date
FROM PMCCONTRACT
```

Then this rolls out:

```
ACCOUNTNUM  RENTALOBJECTID  CONTRACTID  VALIDFROM               VALIDTO
101852      2488            HC000001    1994-03-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
101136      2489            HC000002    1920-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
101352      2491            HC000003    1996-09-16 00:00:00.000 NULL
100687      2492            HC000004    1984-11-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
105160      2499            HC000005    1975-05-02 00:00:00.000 2018-01-31 00:00:00.000
102821      2501            HC000006    1997-09-16 00:00:00.000 NULL
100731      2506            HC000007    1920-01-01 00:00:00.000 2018-11-15 00:00:00.000
102797      2508            HC000008    1998-02-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
102155      2512            HC000009    1981-09-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
102563      2515            HC000010    1965-10-17 00:00:00.000 2017-06-30 00:00:00.000
```

And what I want is that based on the RENTALOBJECTID it will show what the First Next contract on that house was (so it is important that the CONTRACTID remains unique in this table).

Below is the code I use to get it, however, it shows all the following contract changes for that specific RENTALOBJECTID (House).

```
SELECT --TOP 1000
     PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTID
    ,PMCCONTRACT.RENTALOBJECTID
    ,PMCCONTRACT.VALIDFROM
    ,PMCCONTRACT.VALIDTO
    ,P2.CONTRACTID AS 'FirstNextContractId'
    ,P2.VALIDFROM 
    ,P2.VALIDTO 
FROM PMCCONTRACT
    LEFT JOIN PMCCONTRACT P2 
        ON  PMCCONTRACT.RENTALOBJECTID = P2.RENTALOBJECTID
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT 
                RENTALOBJECTID,
                MAX(CONTRACTID) AS CONTRACTID 
            FROM PMCCONTRACT  
            GROUP BY RENTALOBJECTID) X ON X.CONTRACTID = P2.CONTRACTID
WHERE P2.VALIDFROM > PMCCONTRACT.VALIDTO
```

This is what I get when I select only ContractID HC000028, it shows 2 rows, while I want it to show only the first row.

```
CONTRACTID  RENTALOBJECTID  VALIDFROM               VALIDTO                 FirstNextContractId VALIDFROM2              VALIDTO2
HC000028    75              1995-01-01 00:00:00.000 2016-04-30 00:00:00.000 HC009990            2016-05-01 00:00:00.000 2018-11-25 00:00:00.000 --<< Only row I want to show
HC000028    75              1995-01-01 00:00:00.000 2016-04-30 00:00:00.000 HC025218            2018-11-26 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 --Too far in the future
```

Kind regards,

Igor

Comment: Excuse me. Sql-server 2012, updated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a simple [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function is enough. It returns the next row, as defined by partitioning and ordering clauses.

```
SELECT TOP 10
    PMCCONTRACT.ACCOUNTNUM  --Customer
    ,PMCCONTRACT.RENTALOBJECTID --House
    ,PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTID --Contract & Unique index of the table
    ,PMCCONTRACT.VALIDFROM  --Contract Start Date
    ,PMCCONTRACT.VALIDTO    --Contract End Date
    ,LEAD(CONTRACTID) OVER (PARTITION BY RENTALOBJECTID ORDER BY VALIDFROM) AS NextContractID
    ,LEAD(VALIDFROM)  OVER (PARTITION BY RENTALOBJECTID ORDER BY VALIDFROM) AS NextVALIDFROM
    ,LEAD(VALIDTO)    OVER (PARTITION BY RENTALOBJECTID ORDER BY VALIDFROM) AS NextVALIDTO
FROM PMCCONTRACT
;
```